# Cannot have configuration property 'datasources.default.schema-generate' if flyway migration is enabled

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I got an error while updating micronaut from 3.4.3 to latest version 3.10.1. According to the micronaut-flyway documentation, I don't see any problem: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-flyway/latest/guide/index.html

> Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot have configuration property 'datasources.default.schema-generate' if flyway migration is enabled

Application.yml

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: "url"
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: "username"
    password: "password"
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: MYSQL
flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: Well, either you apply your DDL using Flyway or it is done by your ORM. But both does not work out very well. Why do you have both enabled?

Comment: @saw303 that's correct, should be an answer, not a comment 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, either you apply your DDL using Flyway or it is done by your ORM. But both does not work out very well.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why it used to work in the older version 3.4.3?

Comment: Not exactly, but I guess there was missing a configuration validation introduced sometime between Micronaut 3.4.3 and 3.10.1. As you can see this new validation rule helps you easily to find faulty configuration settings.